# Boolean operations affect variables in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am checking the checked state of radio buttons on the page to proceed when they are all pressed:

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="tier0" />
  <input type="radio" name="tier1" />
  <input type="radio" name="tier2" />
  <input id="reset" type="button" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

The evaluation of $result below somehow turns $tier2 to undefined every time tier1 button is pressed and $tier is true, so the $result is never true and I can't proceed. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/29ppxpgm/

```
var $tier0;
var $tier1;
var $tier2;
var $result;

function display() {
  $tier0 = $('[name=tier0]').prop('checked');
  $tier1 = $('[name=tier1]').prop('checked');
  $tier2 = $('[name=tier2]').prop('checked');

  // this boolean operation seems to affect the form elements
  $result = $tier0 && $tier1 && tier2;

  $('#result').html($tier0.toString() + ' & ' + $tier1.toString() + ' & ' + $tier2.toString() + ' => ' + $result.toString());
}

display();

$('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
  display();
});

$('#reset').click(function() {
  $('[type=radio]:checked').prop('checked', false);
  display();
});
```

How come?

Comment: what do you mean "deletes"? Also, what are you trying to do here? I ran your jsfiddle, and it has console errors, so you want to probably solve that problem first and then update your fiddle link.

Comment: Updated the code, spotted the typo and Mritunjay's answer. The question is not worth keeping on SO. (blush).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was not the problem. Problem is here

```
$result = $tier0 && $tier1 && tier2;
```

Here you are saying `&& tier2` which should be `&& $tier2`.

In your demo you are having `$tier1, $tier2, $tier3` the problem was with `tier3`.

## [FIXED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/29ppxpgm/4/)

Comment: Thanks, that's embarassing on my part.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you have a virable typo, you defined a `$tier2`, and you refrence it as `tier2`.

```
function display() {
  $tier0 = $('[name=tier0]').prop('checked');
  $tier1 = $('[name=tier1]').prop('checked');
  $tier2 = $('[name=tier2]').prop('checked');
  $result = $tier0 && $tier1 && *tier2*;  // it should be $tier2
  $('#result').html($tier0.toString() + ' & ' + $tier1.toString() + ' & ' + $tier2.toString() + ' => ' + $result.toString());
}
```

see [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/29ppxpgm/3/).

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is bug here:

```
$result = $tier0 && $tier1 && tier2;
```

this should be like

```
$result = $tier0 && $tier1 && $tier2;
                              ^---------This is added
```